# How to get example django app working on heroku?

Tags: python, git, heroku, git-remote

I'm just trying to start out using heroku to deploy an app written in Flask. So I'm going through the [Getting Started with Python tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#deploy-the-app). So I followed all the steps to set up and prepare the app:

```
# Did a heroku login
MacBook-Air-van-kramer65:zommel kramer65$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: kramer65@mydomain.nl
Password (typing will be hidden):
Found existing public key: /Users/kramer65/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /Users/kramer65/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
Authentication successful.

# clone the repo from github
MacBook-Air-van-kramer65:zommel kramer65$ git clone https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started.git
Cloning into 'python-getting-started'...
remote: Counting objects: 58, done.
remote: Total 58 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
MacBook-Air-van-kramer65:zommel kramer65$ cd python-getting-started/

# Create a heroku app
MacBook-Air-van-kramer65:python-getting-started kramer65$ heroku create --http-git
Creating morning-wave-9853... done, stack is cedar-14
WARNING: Incomplete credentials detected, git may not work with Heroku. Run `heroku login` to update your credentials. See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git#authentication

# Because it says there are incomplete credentials detected I run 'heroku login' again.
MacBook-Air-van-kramer65:python-getting-started kramer65$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: kramer65@mydomain.nl
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.

# And I push the repo
MacBook-Air-van-kramer65:python-getting-started kramer65$ git push heroku master
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I suppose that the repo doesn't know about heroku yet, but it doesn't say anything about this in the tutorial, and I wouldn't know what to set as the remote repo to push it to my heroku instance.

Does anybody know how I can correctly push my stuff to heroku? All tips are welcome!

Comment: The docs do say that doing `heroku create --http-git` associates the remote with your local git repo. That is supposed to work: I can only suggest removing everything and starting again.

Comment: Okay, I just ran `heroku create --http-git`, and miraculously, it now worked! I have no idea why it didn't work in the first place though. But thanks for your time. If you add an answer I can accept it so that people don't look into this anymore..